# Temporary Table in Stored Procedure Not Found in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

I've inherited some code that uses stored procedures and one of them doesn't appear to be working correctly.

The stored procedure uses a temporary table to insert data later in the procedure.  However when I execute the stored procedure, no data is inserted.  When I debug it, I get the error:

`Table 'db.testtable' doesn't exist`

I've stripped down the stored procedure to the following code, and it doesn't work.  I always get the error on the SELECT statement.  Everything looks OK from what I can tell based on the examples I've seen.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS db.insert_record;
CREATE PROCEDURE db.`insert_record`(id int, status int)
BEGIN
    DECLARE code varchar(45);

    DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS testTable;

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE testTable AS (SELECT 'TEST' AS fakeColumn);

    SELECT fakeColumn INTO code FROM testTable;
END;
```

I've also verified that the user I am connected as has the permission to create temporary tables; in fact it has every permission available

**Additional Details**

Running MySQL 5.6 on Windows.

If I take the drop / create / select statements by themselves and run as a script, it behaves as expected.

Using Toad for MySQL to debug the stored procedure.

Comment: Turns out that the issue wasn't a code issue, but a tool issue.  I added select statements all throughout my stored procedure and it returned results from the temporary tables.

For some reason Toad for MySQL wasn't able to handle debugging with temporary tables.  Once I determined that, I found out that there was an issue in the insert statement of the stored proc.

Comment: We are also getting the same error on same environment. In our case this is not everytime, sometime it work and sometime it give error table 'table_name' doesn't exist. In our sp we are droping and creating temp table at proper places (and this was working in previous mysql version 5.5) and this sp is called in a loop for multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem. What other information can you provide?

```sql
mysql> USE `test`;
Database changed

mysql> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------------+
| VERSION()       |
+-----------------+
| 5.5.22-0ubuntu1 |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> DELIMITER //

mysql> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `insert_record`//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE `insert_record`(`id` int, `status` int)
    -> BEGIN
    ->   DECLARE `code` VARCHAR(45);
    ->   DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS `testTable`;
    ->   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `testTable` AS (SELECT 'TEST' AS `fakeColumn`);
    ->   SELECT `fakeColumn` INTO `code` FROM `testTable`;
    ->   SELECT `code`;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> CALL `insert_record`(NULL, NULL)//
+--------+
| `code` |
+--------+
| TEST   |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d5f05/1)</kbd>